# Present perfect & present continous

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Are there any differences between the following sentences:

- I have read this book for two weeks
- I have been reading this book for two weeks

- It has rained for three days
- It has been raining for three days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Present perfect tense** is used to talk about completed activities that took place within a period of time that extends to and includes
>   the present moment.
>
> *I have read this book for two weeks. ( I have taken two weeks' time to complete reading this book)*
>
> We use the **present perfect continuous tense** to talk about an
>   activity or state that extends over a period of time that began in the
>   past, includes the present, and it may extend into the future.
>
> *I have been reading this book for two weeks. ( I have not yet completed reading this book and it will take some days more)*

Comment: Thank you so much for having solved the problem that has been confusing me.