# Present Perfect vs Present Perfect continuous tense differences

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive, perfect-continuous

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

> He **has been studying** in the same class for the last three years.

and

> He **has studied** in the same class for the last three years.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121684/present-perfect-present-continous?rq=1

Comment: Both your examples have the same tense, i.e. perfect. The difference is thus not tense but aspect, with the first having progressive aspect, the second not.