# Can I use present perfect tense here?

Tags: tense

Suppose, I've been fasting for a few hours. Can I say "I have not eaten since breakfast"?
Or should I say "I have not been eating since breakfast"?

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Hi Roksana. Welcome to ELL! Grammatically they are both perfect, but in this context we would say the first. Does the answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121684/present-perfect-present-continous?rq=1) help?

Comment: Or BillJ's comment [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/293895/present-perfect-vs-present-perfect-continuous-tense-differences)?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer because _fasting_ implies more than "a few hours". (We'd call such a short fast "_skipping lunch_"!). If you tell your friends you haven't eaten since breakfast, they might give you a sandwich. If you tell them you haven't **been eating** since breakfast, they might ask what you mean and how long you intend not to eat. (If they were interested in grammar they might ask if your use of the continuous aspect was intentional.)

Comment: What @OldBrixtonian said. So *I haven't smoked since breakfast* might more strongly imply *...because I don't have any cigarettes*, where *I haven't been smoking since breakfast* implies *...because that's when I decided to quit* (or *...because I speak Indian English!* :)

Answer (score 1):

They're both grammatically correct, but the important things are *"What is your context?"* and *"What do you want to express?"*

- I have not eaten since breakfast.

  > Imply that maybe someone asks you to have some meal right now and you want to. You suppose to terminate the activity(state) "not eaten" now.
- I have not been eating since breakfast.

  > Imply that you will keep "not eating."